# Haskell ambiguous type variable for "show"?

Tags: haskell, types, ambiguous

Please see this newly written code now, there is no "read" used, and still I get error on ambiguous "show":

```
data MyType0 a = Tong1 a | Tong2 a  deriving Show
data MyType1 a = Cons1 a | Cons2 a | Cons3 | Cons4 deriving Show
data MyType2 a = MyType2 a deriving Show

fun ((Cons2 s):t:ts) (symseq, MyType2 msg) = (symseq, MyType2 (msg ++ ["You provided wrong symbol: " ++ (show t) ++ " Please provide symbol: " ++ (show Cons3) ]))
--fun ((Cons2 s):t:ts) (symseq, MyType2 msg) = (symseq, MyType2 (msg ++ ["You provided wrong symbol: " ++ (show t) ++ " Please provide symbol: " ]))
fun _ syms                                  = syms
```

The ghci error msg:

```
showerr.hs:6:148:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `show'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `(show Cons3)'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `" Please provide symbol: " ++ (show Cons3)'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely
      `(show t) ++ " Please provide symbol: " ++ (show Cons3)'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

## note that the commented part doesn't give this error. please explain why this is so error.

### original message is kept below.

I got the following code on a site. I know ambiguous type error can come for the "read" function but here i get it for the "show" function too. i find it strange and not understand.

code:

```
main = do run <- getLine
          val <- getLine
          case run of
              "len" -> print . show . len $ (read val)
              "rev" -> print . show . rev $ (read val)
              _ -> putStr "wrong option"

rev :: [a] -> [a]
rev = foldl (flip (:)) []

len :: [a] -> Int
len = foldl (\ac _ -> ac + 1) 0
```

When i load it in ghci i get error.

```
ideone_x0cMx.hs:4:46:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Read a0) arising from a use of `read'
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `(read val)'
    In the expression: print . show . len $ (read val)
    In a case alternative: "len" -> print . show . len $ (read val)

ideone_x0cMx.hs:5:46:
    Ambiguous type variable `a1' in the constraints:
      (Read a1) arising from a use of `read' at ideone_x0cMx.hs:5:46-49
      (Show a1) arising from a use of `show' at ideone_x0cMx.hs:5:32-35
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `(read val)'
    In the expression: print . show . rev $ (read val)
    In a case alternative: "rev" -> print . show . rev $ (read val)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the subexpression `(show Cons3)`, there is no context to determine the type parameter of `MyType1`.

`Cons3` is a constructor for any `MyType1 a`, and calling `show` on it restricts `a` to an instance of `Show`, but beyond that, nothing can be inferred. So the type variable is ambiguous, and since there is no numeric constraint, it cannot be defaulted (unless you enable `ExtendedDefaultRules`).

The type variable could be fixed if you write

```
show (Cons3 `asTypeOf` t)
```

or - for example -

```
show (Cons3 :: MyType1 String)
```

there.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to first question:

Your ambiguity *does* come from the read function!

If you use type-specific versions of len and rev, it'll work. For example, you could replace `len` with `(len :: [Int] -> Int)` or replace `(read val)` with `(read val :: [Int])`

---

Answer to second question:

```
Cons3 :: MyType1 a
```

so Haskell doesn't know what the type `a` is. You could specify explicitly (and it doesn't matter what you choose if you're just `show`ing it):

```
fun ((Cons2 s):t:ts) (symseq, MyType2 msg) = 
    (symseq, MyType2 (msg ++ ["You provided wrong symbol: " ++ (show t) 
       ++ " Please provide symbol: " ++ show (Cons3 :: MyType Int) ]))
```

Normally it can deduce the type of `Cons3` from context, but you create one from the literal and show it straight away, so there isn't a context.

Comment: please see the newly edit code. I removed the "read" function, still I get ambigusus "show" error.

Answer (score 0):

What type should `read val` be? Your code says that it should be a list (because `rev` and `len` both accept all types of list), but doesn't say what it should be a list of.