# No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of ‘mymerge’

Tags: haskell

I'm going through "Programming in Haskell" and I'm trying to merge two sorted lists. This is my code:

```
mymerge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mymerge xs [] = xs
mymerge [] ys = ys
mymerge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     = x : mymerge xs (y:ys)
                      | otherwise = y : mymerge (x:xs) ys
```

It works in all cases except when I try to define a test as:

```
t72 = mymerge [] []
```

The error is:

```
No instance for (Ord a0) arising from a use of ‘mymerge’
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Relevant bindings include t72 :: [a0] (bound at ch06.hs:109:1)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance (Ord a, Ord b) => Ord (Either a b)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
  instance forall (k :: BOX) (s :: k). Ord (Data.Proxy.Proxy s)
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Proxy’
  instance (GHC.Arr.Ix i, Ord e) => Ord (GHC.Arr.Array i e)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Arr’
  ...plus 26 others
In the expression: mymerge [] []
In an equation for ‘t72’: t72 = mymerge [] []
```

I suspect it's trying to tell me that there's not enough information to infer the type of []. It works if I explicitly define the type of the function:

```
t72 :: Ord a => [a]
t72 = mymerge [] []
```

Is this the idiomatic way to get it working?

UPDATE: I would not mark this a duplicate as suggested, the answers to the other question do not mention the monomorphism restriction.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell ambiguous type variable for "show"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109576/haskell-ambiguous-type-variable-for-show)

Comment: It sounds like you understand the issue. You would normally just give the argument a concrete type, like `merge ([] :: [Int]) []`

Comment: @karafka, I have GHC 7.10.3

Comment: @jberryman, I don't know enough Haskell to judge if this is a duplicate of the question you mentioned :-)

Comment: The reason for the error is the same as in the proposed duplicate -- that there's an ambiguous type variable that needs resolving -- though the specifics are somewhat different so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this the infamous [monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction)? In GHCi 8.0.1 this works as expected without annotations:

```
Prelude> :t mymerge [] []
mymerge [] [] :: Ord a => [a]
```

Because:

```
Prelude> :showi language
base language is: Haskell2010
with the following modifiers:
  -XNoDatatypeContexts
  -XExtendedDefaultRules
  -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
  -XNondecreasingIndentation
```

So this also works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

mymerge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mymerge xs [] = xs
mymerge [] ys = ys
mymerge (x:xs) (y:ys) | x < y     = x : mymerge xs (y:ys)
                      | otherwise = y : mymerge (x:xs) ys

t72 = mymerge [] []
```

In short, by default the type of `t72` will be inferred to be less polymorphic than you'd expect.

Comment: Right, good point. So `t72 = mymerge [] []` throwing that error at compile time is due to the monomorphism restriction, however you'll need the ambiguity to be resolved at some point if you want to ever use `t72`, e.g. by printing it, doing `== []`, etc. In ghci we can say `t72 == []` but that is due to extended defaulting rules

Comment: Yes I agree, with `NoMonomorphismRestriction` enabled or without it with a type annotation from the original question `t72 :: Ord a => [a]` it is still polymorphic so neighter of the above may be enough in order to fix all issues in all parts of the code.